# How is this trigonometric substitution achieved for this simple capacitor circuit equation?

Tags: electric-circuits, differentiation

In a simple circuit with one capacitor and one AC source, where the equation of the source voltage is `v(t) = Acos(ωt)`, I was trying to follow how they found the equation for the current as a function of time, and they made a substitution I was unable to follow. It can be seen on page 3 of [this PDF](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-071j-introduction-to-electronics-signals-and-measurement-spring-2006/lecture-notes/capactr_inductr.pdf), around 1.9.

The equation `i(t) = -CAωsin(ωt)` magically transforms into `i(t) = CAωcos(ωt + pi/2)`.

I don't know why the negative went away, and I have less than a great understanding of the pi/2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a math question, but it's just a trigonometric identity.

$$\cos\Big(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\Big)=\sin(x)\\$$
Or
$$\cos\Big(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\Big)=-\sin(x)$$

Comment: Right you are. I guess I've forgotten my trigonometric identities. I'm in the process of relearning things from years ago that I haven't thought about for years, for fun. Thanks! (Have to wait a couple min to accept the answer.)

Comment: No problem, good luck!